# Cordova/PhoneGap rendering local PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cordova

I'm making a web using PhoneGap. I need to use a PHP page, but I want a real fluid website, so I opted for replacing a `div` with some PHP using JavaScript when loaded.

When I launch the page "mypage.html" I check the user connection with this function:

```
     <script> 
        function checkConnection(){

   var online, speed;
   /*
   condizione di controllo per determinare se l'app viene correntemente testata 
   in un simulatore o dispositivo mobile (quindi utilizzando PhoneGap) o in un normale browser
   che supporta l'HTML5
   */

   if(typeof cordova != "undefined"){      

                /*
       si tratta di un dispositivo vero e proprio o di un simulatore, quindi
       utilizziamo il plugin "Connection" messo a disposizione da Phonegap
       */
       var networkState = navigator.connection.type;  
       var states = {};
       states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown';
       states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet';
       states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi';
       states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell_2G';
       states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell_3G';
       states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell_4G';
       states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell_generic';
       states[Connection.NONE]     = 'None';

       //determino il tipo di connessione in base all'oggetto "states" appena definito grazie al plugin Phonegap
       var connType = states[networkState]; 

       if(connType=='None')
         online = false;
      else{
         online = true; 
         if(connType=="Cell_2g" || connType=="Cell_generic")
            speed="slow";
         else
            speed="fast";
       }

   }else{      

      /*
      si tratta di un normale browser desktop o mobile, quindi
      utilizziamo la funzionalità HTML5
      */
       online = navigator.onLine;

       if(online){
         var conn = navigator.connection || {'bandwidth':'0'};
         //utilizziamo il metodo "bandwidth" per determinare la velocità di connessione, il quale restituisce un valore numerico che indica la larghezza di banda della connessione corrente       
         if(conn.bandwidth>2)
            speed="fast";
        else
         speed="slow";

       }

   }  
   return online?speed:false;

}

var deviceConnection = checkConnection();
if(deviceConnection){
   if(deviceConnection == "slow"){
      //gestione connnessione lenta

   }else{
      //gestione connnessione veloce


   }
}else{   
   /*
   gestione transizioni ed effetti per mostrare all'utente 
   un gradevole avviso di mancanza di connessione  
   */
   location.href="errorconnection.html"; 


}

      </script>
```

This is the AJAX code :

```
<div id="container">
 <script>
        $( "#container" ).load("http://www.mywebsite.org/FOLDER/page.php #container");
 </script>  
</div>
```

When I launch "mypage.html" on my browser locally it works ok, except for that it shows for a bit of php code. When I launch "mypage.html" on PhoneGap it shows me only a part of the php code and nothing else.

```
...

</head>
<body style="background-color:#e20a7e">
                                <div id="navigation">
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tr valign="bottom">
                                            <td valign="middle" width="25%" align="center">

                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="bottom" width="50%" align="center">
                                                <img src="IMG/LOGO-WHITE.png" class="logonbar" alt="DONUT"/>
                                            </td>
                             <td onClick="window.location='loginpage.php'" width="25%" align="center" valign="middle">
                                           <img src="IMG/icon/usr.png" class="icons3"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                </div>


                       <div id="container">



    <?php 
    $DBhost = "localhost";
    $DBuser = "xx";
    $DBpass = "";
    $DBName = "xx";

    $table = "Database";

    mysql_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass) or die("mysql_error()");
    @mysql_select_db("$DBName") or die("mysql_error()");



    $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM `Database` ORDER BY data DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlquery);
    $number = mysql_num_rows($result);



    $i = 0;

    while ($i < $number) {

          $festa[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"festa");
          $luogo[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"luogo");
          $idfesta[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"ID");
          $data[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"data");  
          $nomeimg[$i] = mysql_result($result,$i,"nomeimg");

          $data[$i] = data_eng_to_it_($data[$i]);




           echo"
                                     <!--INIZIO DIV EVENTO-->

                                    <a href=\"pagevento.html?ID=$idfesta[$i]\">
                                    <div style=\"width:90%; display:block; margin:0 auto; 
                                                    padding-top:10px; margin-top:10px; padding-left:10px;
                                               background-color:#FFF; padding-bottom:10px; 
                                               border-left:solid 5px #e20a7e;


                                                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                                                -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                                                box-shadow:         0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);\">

                                    <table width=\"100%\" style='table-layout:fixed'>
                                            <tr valign=\"middle\">
                                                <td valign=\"middle\" align=\"center\" class=\"evntfoto\"
                                                     style=\"background-image:url(foto/$nomeimg[$i]);
                                                             background-position:center;
                                                           background-size: cover;\">
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign=\"top\"  align=\"left\" id=\"evnttxt\">
                                    &nbsp; &nbsp; <font color=\"#0066FF\" size=\"+2\"> <b> ".$festa[$i]." </b></font> <br>
                                    &nbsp; &nbsp; ".$data[$i]."  <br>
                                    &nbsp; &nbsp; <font color=\"#585858\"> ".$luogo[$i]." </font> <br>
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </table>
                                            </div>
                                            </a>

                                     <!--FINE DIV EVENTO--> 
    ";

    $i++;
    }
    ?>                      
                                    </div>              
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and when I run the page it shows me:

```
".$festa[$i]."
".$data[$i]."
".$luogo[$i]."

"; $i++; ?>
```

but only from PhoneGap. In other browsers, Safari on Mac, Google Chrome on Mac and Safari on iPhone it works correctly, and shows me that code for only a second. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us out. What is this "a bit some php code" that shows? I can't see any PHP in your code samples.

Comment: @Drakes i just edited

Comment: You cannot use PHP in cordova/phonegap. You can use JS to call to external PHP pages though. PHP is a serverside language that must run a webserver. Cordova/phonegap is not a webserver.

Comment: I have to agree with @DawsonLoudon, you cannot PHP in phonegap, unless you somehow make it into a server.

Comment: I'm not using php i'm only loading my #container div from my php file that stays on a web server @DawsonLoudon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary:** You are loading both a local and a server version of a PHP page at the same time, and you are having a CORS issue with the server load on PhoneGap.

---

I was able to reproduce your unexpected output here (http://jsfiddle.net/Drakes/gq0my18r/). I took your HTML/PHP code and rendered it as HTML only. This was the output:

```
    ".$festa[$i]." 
    ".$data[$i]." 
    ".$luogo[$i]." 
"; $i++; } ?>
```

You might be serving a local copy of your PHP file on your phone, and then fetching a server version, or your server is responding with an unprocessed version of your PHP page somehow.

Now, you said something interesting:

> ... in other browsers, safari on mac, google chrome on mac and safari on iphone it works correctly, and shows me that code for only a second

This leads me to believe that you are rendering the local HTML version, then somehow requesting the server version. I looked at the links you supplied me in the comments and noticed something striking in your HTML that explains everything.

You have

```
   <div id="container">
 <script>
    $( "#container" ).load("http://www.bparty.org/APP/eventi.php #container");
</script>  
   </div>
```

and

```
   <div id="container">
<script>
    $( "#container" ).load( "eventi.php #container" );
</script>                        
   </div>
```

on the *same page*. There is a myriad of trouble happening here. Now you have multiple `container` divs with the same id, and there is a race condition to load your local PHP version (which can't render locally), and then it is being replaced with the server version which can render PHP. This explains that one-second lag you described in some browsers.

### CORS

However, your **huge** problem with PhoneGap and PHP is that you cannot *simply*  load external pages into your phone app using AJAX because of something called CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing). It's just disallowed. We're getting into hacky-land now, but you can do some [magic](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html) and make it work. I'm not recommending this outright, but you can make your setup work by adding this to the top of `eventi.php`:

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Also, please, please stop using `#container` in your fetch URL `"http://www.bparty.org/APP/eventi.php #container"`. Who knows how PhoneGap handles that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/index.html), Phonegap can only handle files with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. If you want to use PHP or any other language for your application, you have to handle PHP on your server, and from a mobile app request only static data and JS