# How to run php file in phonegap?

Tags: php, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I am developing a mobile application in phonegap. My app works in a way that when a user submits a form, the data gets posted to a file called functions.php (present in the root folder) and functions.php parses data and sends to my rest application using curl. When I run this application in a web server, it works perfectly fine but when i run it in phonegap and post data to functions.php, instead of running functions.php as a function, it displays all the code of functions.php on the mobile screen and stops there. Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: PhoneGap doesn't have a PHP interpreter. You still need to use a webserver to run PHP, as PHP is a server-side language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova/PhoneGap rendering local PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566223/cordova-phonegap-rendering-local-php)

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe is what happens when you try to run a php file from a webserver that does not have php installed, so it sounds like you are trying to load the functions.php locally from within your phonegap app. Phonegap has its own webserver, which is not a php server, so it won't run php files. If you need to interact with php/sql/other remote stuff, you should be using ajax requests to interact with the remote (non-phonegap) server. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-get-ajax-working-with-phonegap